How can I use Orange for Flood Forecasting purpose for a Hydrological Station on a River?
There is a Hydrological Station on a river having the provision of water level readings through gauge/staff posts (hourly during the monsoon). There are old such datasets of water levels time stamped. Can only this much data/parameter be sufficient for training AI/ML based softwares/models and utilized for predictive/forecasting purpose for water levels in the river at that station?
Or is there any need for giving rainfall data, or other upstream stations datasets?

I am confused, you have water level data and you want to predict water level? looks like there is sth I didn't understand in your question. But in any case, the more data you can get and the better quality it is (probably than rainfall would be interesting), the better will be the results of your ML model.
